# @media (max-width or min-width) for video

Tags: html, css, video, hidden

I want to ask - this function for an image to hide or reveal at a given resolution (sample in code) - **can it be applied to video as well**? Thanks

```css
@media (max-width:375px) {
                img#eq {
                display: none;
            }
```

```html
<img id="eq"  src="assets/images/picture.jpg">
```

Comment: can you elaborate more on that ? You want to hide a video on a specific viewport ? If so then yes it works with videos as well

Comment: I want the video to be displayed only on displays of at least 375px, smaller ones are not displayed.

Comment: this is not a function, this is a media query declration within css. It works for everything that can be selected with css (this includes videos).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Media Queries` can be used always within CSS and works on everything that can eb addressed by CSS. This also includes videos as the snippet below shows.

```css
video {
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen
  and (max-width: 374px) {
    video {
      display: none;
    }
}

@media only screen
  and (min-width: 375px) {
    video {
      display: block;
    }
}
```

```html
<video controls>
  <source src="https://www.tacoshy.de/stackoverflow/testvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes it will work and first you want to add a meta tag in your html head
it is look like

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
```